# Filter home_url for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I would like to change the home_url for a custom post type that I have created.

The reason I would like to change the home_url is so that the site logo then links to a different URL when someone is viewing a custom post.

The custom post type is named 'usa', therefore I want to change the logo / home url to link to mysite.com/usa/

I have used the code below to achieve this, however I get errors because other links that make use of home_url, such as menu links, then have 'usa' appended to them, e.g mysite.com/usa/example-post/usa/

Does someone know a better implementation?

```
add_filter( 'home_url', 'custom_home_url' );

function custom_home_url( $url )
{
if( is_singular('us') )
    return $url .'/usa';
    else {
            return $url;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could just use JS to change the links on page load?

Comment: Are you using template files for this USA CPT?

Comment: No at the moment I'm just using a plugin to implement and then working off the standard template files.

Comment: See your problem is that you can't really ascertain what does and doesn't use `home_url` in your functions.php and therefore, you can't pick which one should use the new URL instead of the original. What I would suggest is putting your code in the default header template file *(where the menu code is)*. You can use the `is_singular()` to check if you're on the right page to swap the link. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that does make sense. Thanks for your header example below, I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter generally seems fine.

I'd probably filter `option_home` instead of `home_url`, but it results in the same thing for most use cases (`bloginfo("home")` will work and so will `get_home_url()`, but `get_option("home")` will only work correctly with `option_home`).

Comment: Using `option_home` does have better results but some URLs are returning mysite.com/usa/usa/example-post/

Comment: Are they using custom permalinks by any change? If they have a permalink set to usa/example-post/, they'll add that to the home-url, therefore making it /usa/usa/example-post/. Otherwise, maybe those links are written in the template in a special way?

Comment: The slug is rewritten for the custom post type, otherwise the name of the custom post type gets used, which is the same anyway. Without rewriting the slug I still get /usa/usa/example-post/

Comment: Maybe fix it the dirty & easy way and use output buffers, then replace /usa/usa/ with /usa/?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting this in the file that contains your menu code, the header file usually. You can just check the page on load to see if the page your on needs the USA appending to the link.

Here is an example that could be used for any element within a page.

**HEADER.PHP**

```
<?php
if( is_singular('us') ) { 
  $url = site_url( '/usa/' );
} else { 
  $url = site_url();
}
?>
<nav>
  <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="logo">MY LOGO</a>
</nav>
```

`site_url()` by default will just give you your website URL but it can also take an extra `$path` parameter to append to the end of the URL. This is why I have put `'/usa/'` inside `site_url()` above.